# Adding shadow to subview interfer with parent view (iOS swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, shadow, shadowpath

Any idea on how to achieve this shadow effect ?
This screen is from the android app  I am using swift (ios)

[image]

note that I have two views and when I add shadow to both they interfer and get darker

Answer (score 0):

The trick to achieve this is to put another view in the middle that clips the content of your top view. Examine the following code:

```
let bottomShadowView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100.0, y: 100.0, width: 200.0, height: 100.0))
bottomShadowView.backgroundColor = .white
bottomShadowView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
bottomShadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
bottomShadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
bottomShadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 8
view.addSubview(bottomShadowView)

let bottomClipView = UIView(frame: bottomShadowView.bounds)
bottomClipView.layer.cornerRadius = bottomShadowView.layer.cornerRadius
bottomClipView.clipsToBounds = true
bottomShadowView.addSubview(bottomClipView)

let topShadowView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 200.0, height: 50.0))
topShadowView.backgroundColor = .white
topShadowView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
topShadowView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
topShadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
topShadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 8
bottomClipView.addSubview(topShadowView)
```

Note that you can do most of this in interface builder but the code should give you a better understanding on what is going on.

The `bottomClipView` needs to be of the same size as the parent shadow view and have same features such as corner radius. Then simply apply `clipsToBounds` so that anything you place on this view will not draw anything out of its bounds and will not interfere with the shadow.